# How to make faster Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode6

How to make faster Xcode 6. Its running quite slow with 4 GB RAM 2.5 GHz i5.Instead of upgrading system , there is any way to make it little bit faster. Thanks in advance for your suggestion and tips.

Comment: this question does not relate to a specific programming problem

Comment: where I state that Its is programming issue . I want know if there have anything which help us better experience with xcode 6. I hope many people facing this issue.

Comment: SO if used to ask programming related problems.. Hope you got my point now..

Comment: So above question is not eligible for this forum . Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Look at the sentence where you say "instead of upgrading system"... That's where you explictly refused the solution to your problem. Well, one colleague of mine got a _major_ speed improvement by turning off the virus checker that for some reason he insisted on using...

Comment: @PhatWrat, Nice to see that you are editing some questions and killing this tag, but **please** also fix all other problems with the post. Otherwise your edits may start getting rejected.

Comment: Sorry-just trying to be helpful. I'll be more thurough on future batches...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As my experience, SVN or Git can make some problem with warning. You can disable Source Control to make your xcode faster.

Go to Xcode -> Preferences ... -> Source Control -> untick Enable Source Control

You should restart xcode to get the effect.

Also you can use some Ram cleaner (you can search on appstore), it will be the best.
And you can download smcFanControl (a dirty way) to kick you fan up to 6400 rpm. it will cool your mac down and make things better.